# unknown colomn 'offset' in 'field list' drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, import

I'm using drupal 6, with node import 6.x-1.0-rc4. I just backed up my database and install a new fresh drupal site. Now, I try to import a .csv file with node import. But I get the following error. What could be the reason?

```
user warning: Unknown column 'offset' in 'field list' query:
INSERT INTO node_import_tasks (name, uid, created, changed, fid, has_headers, file_options, ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dump's original database has an 'offset' field which isn't present in the database you're trying to load the dump into.

You can add it via

```
ALTER TABLE node_import_tasks ADD offset XXX;
```

where XXX is the type (I'm guessing it'd be an integer).

But be aware that most likely your imports won't work properly, as they're for a different version of Drupal, and you can very well break Drupal by importing "bad" data.

Answer (score 1):

Mark B is correct about needing this extra field; however, I think that your problem could probably be solved more easily and safely by going to `yoursite.com/update.php` when you are logged in as an admin.

Whenever you update modules or core, you need to run go to update.php in order to run scripts for performing various update tasks ... especially tasks which have to do with changing the tables of your database.

If you've already added this table manually, it's possible that when you get around to running update.php, it will try to add this table again.